# How to get the expected jolt output based on the given condition

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

In the input you can see 3 users and their details. for suppose there is a new user/customer for us. we need to take their details and add it in a subarray with all the input fields given by them. When ever an user is added we need to add those details and one more "community" should be added in "v2_communities". So the next time an user is added "community3" will be added in "v2_communities"

input:

```
    "v3_users": [
        {
            "username": "user1",
            "password": "password1",
            "privacy_password": "privacy1"
        },
        {
            "username": "user2",
            "password": "password2",
            "privacy_password": "privacy2",
            "engineId":"80000000308"
        },
        {
            "username": "user3",
            "password": "password3",
            "privacy_password": "privacy3",
            "engineId":"8000020305"
        }
    ],
    "v2_communities": ["community1","community2"]
    }
```

output:

```
 "v3_users": [
        {
            "username": "user1",
            "password": "password1",
            "privacy_password": "privacy1"
        },
        {
            "username": "user2",
            "password": "password2",
            "privacy_password": "privacy2",
            "engineId":"80000000308"
        },
        {
            "username": "user3",
            "password": "password3",
            "privacy_password": "privacy3",
            "engineId":"8000020305"
        },
        {
            "username": "user4",
            "password": "password4",
            "privacy_password": "privacy4",
            "engineId":"80000203078"
        }
    ],
    "v2_communities": ["community1","community2","community3"]
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the expected output using jolt transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78042175/how-to-get-the-expected-output-using-jolt-transformation)

Comment: no but I ve figured out the solution for this. Thank you